# Code golf: Diffie-Hellman key exchange

Tags: cryptography, code-golf, public-key

Back in the ITAR era, there was a [popular sig that performed Diffie-Hellman key exchange](http://www.cypherspace.org/adam/rsa/perl-dh.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -- -export-a-crypto-system-sig Diffie-Hellman-2-lines
($g,$e,$m)=@ARGV,$m||die"$0 gen exp mod\n";print`echo "16dio1[d2%Sa2/d0<X+d
*La1=z\U$m%0]SX$e"[$g*]\EszlXx+p|dc`
```

With a modern dc, this can be reduced quite a bit to:

```
dc -e '16dio???|p'
```

While the modern dc form with the modular exponentiation command ('|' computes g^e % m via efficient exponential doubling) is likely unbeatable other than perhaps [APL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237496/code-golf-factorials), can the original form be improved upon?  Keep in mind that the e and m values will be very large; they will both be on the order of 1024 bits each for cryptographic security.

Comment: May I suggest marking this with `language-agnostic` and `rosetta-stone`

Comment: `rosetta-stone` if you want implementations in many languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those unfamiliar with Diffie-Hellman or `dc` (or Perl): all the program does, if you run it as "`program g x m`", is output g<sup>x</sup>(mod m), where g, x, and m are given in hexadecimal. E.g.

```
./dh.pl 10 2 9
4
```

because 10 is sixteen and 10<sup>2</sup> is two-hundred-and-fifty-six, which is 4 mod 9.

And the `dc` command `16dio???|p` says:

- push **sixteen** onto the stack,
- **d**uplicate it,
- set **i**nput radix (base) to the result of popping the stack (16, hex),
- set **o**utput radix to the result of popping the stack (16),
- get three lines of input and execute them (so if the three lines are three numbers g, x, m, they get pushed onto the stack),
- do the exponentiation g<sup>x</sup>(mod m),
- **p**rint it.

Given that `dc` has a one-character command "`|`" for computing "g<sup>x</sup>(mod m)" which is precisely the problem, I find it highly unlikely that it can be improved upon in any programming language. `dc` just happens to be a tool for exactly this problem; it's no contest comparing a programming language to the right tool. (E.g. any common programming language will take more than two characters to list files in a directory, while "`ls`" is only 2.)

That said, I note that `dc -e '16dio???|p'` seems to want me to input the numbers in three different lines (at least on the `dc` I have here), so it ***can be improved*** to something that can handle them all on the same line :-)

`dc -e '16dio?|p'`

Comment: Perhaps it is like the factorial golf problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237496/code-golf-factorials  APL won with the very concise '?!' program, which is hard to beat in any other language.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt anything will top the modern dc version! Here's Python:

```
def f(g,x,m):
 def h(n):return int(`n`,16)
 return h(g)**h(x)%h(m)
```

It won't work in Python 3.0 as we've [phased out reverse quotes](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).

Comment: One problem with this solution is that this will take a very, very long time if h is large.  For cryptographic security, h will have on the order of 1024 bits.  I'll update the question to include this detail.